# What separates gene loci?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

Introns are sections of noncoding DNA that separate exons within a gene locus. However, between different gene loci, I also would assume there to be noncoding regions of DNA. What are these regions called? (And if my assumption is wrong, then please correct me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These regions, if unannotated, are simply called **intergenic regions**.

Sometimes, if a large section of chromatin is regulated by an [enhancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancer_%28genetics%29)/silencer/locus control element, then there are [boundary elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_%28genetics%29) that demarcate this chromatin region and prevent the spread of the chromatin state to neighbouring regions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be valid to call them "intergenic regions", but this is just another way of saying that they are the regions between genes. I don't think you can do much more because they are not homogenous in nature. Some may be short and perhaps lack any other function than that described by @WYSIWYG, others may be very long and have enhancers and regulatory elements for proximal or distal genes, simple repeated sequences, pseudogenes, replication origins etc. etc.