# What sequences are between adjacent genes?

Tags: molecular-genetics, human-genome

The human genome has a lot of non-coding regions, which include regulatory elements, repetitive DNA, and introns. Suppose there are two adjacent genes on a chromosome, and their positions on the chromosome are, say,

For the first gene: 11,785,723 to 11,803,245 bp.

For the second gene: 11,806,096 to 11,806,143 bp. These values **include** their regulatory elements, promoter and introns as well.

So what sequence is present between bases 11,803,245 and 11,806,096? Are they satellite sequences? Is this non-coding, non-regulatory region 11,803,245 to 11,806,096 bp heterochromatin?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/43120/3340

Comment: It is the same question, but with an additional query - are those regions heterochromatin? Are all regions of repititive DNA, like microsatellites, heterochromatin? Or is heterochromatin only the repetitive sequences of telomeres and centomeres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The intergenic regions are not necessarily heterochromatin. Chromatin conformations are usually very long range and are not usually confined to a single gene. The spread of chromatin state can be prevented by [insulators/boundary elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_(genetics)), which again are not a part of the transcribed region. The intergenic regions can also harbour distal regulatory elements such as enhancers and silencers; they can have microsatellites, transposons etc too. To know what all are there in a specific region, you can look at the different tracks in the [UCSC genome browser](http://genome.ucsc.edu).

In short, there can be functional and/or non-functional DNA in-between the transcribed regions.

Repeat regions need not be heterochromatinized and conversely not all heterochromatic regions consist of repeats.

Comment: Can it at least be said all repeat sequences are non-functional?

Comment: @Charles No you can't really say that. Telomeric repeats are important. So are centromeric repeats. There are non-tandem repeats like LINEs; they have been implicated in somatic heterogeneity in the brain.

Comment: Are all non-functional parts of the genome - such as non-functional satellite sequences - heterochromatinized?